# Change location of maildir

Tags: email, postfix, opensuse

Standard Linux installation provide a maildir in `/var/spool/mail/$user` (that's actually a single file holding all emails, not a "mail directory"), soft-linked by `/var/mail/`.

I'm going to set up managed email on my installation, and I want to store mail in a separate partition that can be attached to the file system in case of server reimage (I already enforced this disaster-recovery measure for services such as `mysql`). The separate filesystem is `/home`.

So I would like system mail to be delivered to `/home/$user/.mail[/]` (final `/` in brackets because I'm not sure whether to include mail in a directory or not).

**Currently**, I run email for my own domain by redirecting all email to my ISP's email, which will not be forever (in case I change ISP I must migrate all email to the new ISP), so Postfix is instructed to redirect everyting directed to `*@example.org` to `user@example.com`.

I was thinking about using `Dovecot` as email server, as it fully supports SSL.

So first, before configuring Dovecot, **how do I tell the system** to deliver mail in a different directory than /var/spool? Please mind that cron regularly sends email to `root` when jobs don't write to `/dev/null`, so the configuration must be system-wide.

Comment: Possible solution: soft-linking /var/spool/mail to /home/mail will hold the mail queue under /home

Comment: Typically dovecot is the IMAP/POP3 daemon used by the recipients to read email and neither the incoming/outgoing SMTP server, nor the [local delivery agent](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MDA). To change the location of the default mail dirctory you most likely need both to change where sendmail/postfix/exim or whatever you're using delivers email, as well as Dovecot's configuration.

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ I applied HBruijn's answer on my server and it works great. Can you please accept his answer if it answers your question?

Comment: Sorry that I involuntarily buried it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is recommended to use the [Maildir](http://www.qmail.org/man/man5/maildir.html) directory format to store email rather than the older mbox format. The Maildir format is well supported by Dovecot and has some advantages (no locking, allows for easy incremental back-ups and restoring of individual messages.) So you’ll need to assign a directory.

It is convention to store mail in a `~/Maildir` directory in a user’s home directory, but nothing prevents you from using another (hidden) directory.

You configure both the Maildir format as well as its location with the Postfix [home_mailbox](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#home_mailbox) setting:

```
sudo postconf -e "home_mailbox = Maildir/"
```

This is also the default location configured for most Dovecot packages.

The alternative is to configure Postfix to leave local mail delivery to the Dovecot [LDA](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/LDA/Postfix) or [LMTP](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/protocols/lmtp_server/).

Then configure Dovecot to look for mail in the correct location as well:

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
```

In case of mail users actually having local user accounts (instead of only existing as [virtual mail users](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/VirtualUsers)), you may want to populate `/etc/skell` with a Maildir and a welcome message for new users.